# Suppose we know that $Ax= (2,4,2)^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations

Suppose we know that
$$Ax = \begin{bmatrix}
2\\ 4\\ 2\end{bmatrix}.$$
$x$ is:

$$\begin{bmatrix}2\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} +c \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix} + d\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix} $$

What’s the dimension of the row space of $A$?

since there is a solution I think the dimension of the null space must be $< n$ if I know the dimention of the nullspace then I can use it to find the rank of A

I know $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix

What is $A$?

Comment: Please avoid "tall"  formulas in the subject line.

Comment: Please **don't** do that. Display equations and "tall" equations in subject lines mess up the displays.

Comment: Do you mean that $A(2+c,c,d)^T=(2,4,2)^T$ for *some* values of $(c,d)$ or for *all* of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ is $3 \times 3$, and since the null space of $A$ is of dimension $2$, then the row space of $A$ is of dimension $1$.  This follows from the Rank-Nullity theorem which states that for an $m \times n$ matrix $A$

$\text{Rank}(A) + \text{Nullity}(A) = n $

Recalling the

$\text{Rank}(A) = \dim(\text{Row Space of A}) = \dim(\text{Column Space of A})$

Then it follows that

$\dim(\text{Row Space of A}) = 1 $

Therefore, $A$ is of the form

$ A = \mathbf{u} \mathbf{v}^T $

And we have to find $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$

Since $[1, 1, 0]^T$ and $[0, 0, 1]^T$ are in the null space of $A$ then

$ \mathbf{v}^T [1, 1, 0]^T = 0 $  and $ \mathbf{v}^T [0, 0, 1]^T = 0 $, which implies that

$ \mathbf{v} = k [1, -1, 0]^T $

Finally,

$A [2, 0, 0]^T = [2,4,2]^T$, hence

$ \mathbf{u} \mathbf{v}^T [2, 0, 0]^T = \mathbf{u} (2 k) = [2, 4, 2]^T $

From which $\mathbf{u} = \dfrac{1}{k} [1, 2, 1]^T $

And,

$A = \mathbf{u} \mathbf{v}^T = k \bigg(\dfrac{1}{k} \bigg) [1, 2, 1]^T [1, -1, 0] = \begin{bmatrix} 1& -1& 0 \\ 2& -2& 0 \\ 1& -1& 0 \end{bmatrix} $

Comment: how do you know the dimension of the nullspace is 2?

Comment: why is that [1,1,0]T and [0,0,1]T are in the null space of A?

Comment: Because $\mathbf{x}$ as given in the problem is of the form $\mathbf{x_0} + c \mathbf{v_1} + d \mathbf{v_2} $.  The linearly independent vectors $\mathbf{v_1}$ and $\mathbf{v_2}$ span the null space of $A$ (because multiplying A by these vectors does not change the resulting vector, which is $[2,4,2]^T$.